# MVC omit optional page parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following URL in mind:

```
/restaurants/italian/miami.html
/restaurants/italian/miami-p2.html
```

Using these routes

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/{branch}/{city}-p{page}.html",
                new { controller = "Branch", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/{branch}/{city}.html",
                new { controller = "Branch", action = "Index", page = 1 });
```

Now for my question, i want to make "-p{page}" portion of the url optional, not just the {page} parameter. That way i can use a single route and also use it to map outbound urls with `Url.RouteUrl(RouteValueDictionary)` (which then auto removes the page portion if the page parameter in the dictionary is 1).

Comment: *Why* are you adding `.html` to your routes? The whole point of routes is to *not* point to a physical page.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but it isnt my decision unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this i needed 3 routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/{branch}/{city}.html",
                new { controller = "Branch", action = "Index" },
                new { page = "1" });

routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/{branch}/{city}-p{page}.html",
                new { controller = "Branch", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/{branch}/{city}.html",
                new { controller = "Branch", action = "Index", page = 1 });
```

This way i can map all the urls inbound with the second and third route and outbound with the first and second.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand well what you would like, still somehow I think that using some [regular expression constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) might solve your problem. Maybe somehow like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/{branch}/{citywithp}{page}.html",
            new { controller = "Branch", action = "Index" },
            new {citywithp = @"p-\d+$" } );
```

Comment: Ok, well I am happy that it helped somehow... :)